# Add a number to a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file

I need to check a long list of variables to see if they equal to a number. I need to do this without listing the variables again. This is part of the code.

```
set wp1=10
set wp2=123
set wp3=142
ect.....
set change=+16
set "wp=wp%num%"
set num=0
:check
set /a num=%num%+1
if %wp% LEQ 48 set change=-8 
if %wpn% EQU 904 (
goto change
) Else (
goto check
)
```

The problem is that %wp% equals wp1,2,3, ... ,but does not have a real representation of wp1,2,3,.... I need to find out how to make %wp% equal to what %wp1,2,3,..% is.

Comment: Use delayed expansion.  `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` then `set "wp=!wp%num%!"`.  Also, indent your parenthetical code (your `goto` commands).  Not everything in Windows batch scripting has to be left-justified.  indenting makes it easier to follow code block nesting and closures.

Comment: `I need to do this without listing the variables again`  <--- What does that mean?

Comment: When I mean list the variables again I don't want to have  to rewrite the variables in order to find information. Because of the variables constantly change and the amount of space they take up listing them will not work.

Comment: @user3325754 - Still clear as mud. Your title says one thing, the text of the question another, and your code is incomplete, so impossible to interpret your intent. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Wp1 - wp90.. is what i need to check for to see if the variable plus or minus will equal less then or equal to a number that I choose. The ex in the code is 48. If so i need to change the number by an amount. The example is -8. In order to check this with out listing all the variables. I am trying to have the code go through them one by one. set /a num=%num%+1 is the counter for going through wp1 ,wp2 .. The problem is that this is not working. set "wp=wp%num%" This tells it to add together wp+the number. The result is wp1 , wp2.. But  wp1 is a new variable and does not equal its number.